# How to set system-wide proxy address using shell script?

Tags: networking, scripts, proxy

I want to set system Proxy address through my Qt application. So i was wondering if i could write a script which can be executed by my application every time to change the proxy address.

I tried :

```
 #! /bin/sh 
 echo "# Generated by Application"

 export $1
 echo "Proxy Address ${1}
```

but this script was not successful. I think it was unable to execute "export" command.

Can anyone help me resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "# Generated by Application"
export http_proxy='http://$1/'
export ftp_proxy='http://$1/'
```

**Note:**

- your argument string($1) should be like this

`user_id:pass@proxy.server.addr:proxy_port`

- If you do not use userid and password then argument string($1) should be

`proxy.server.addr:proxy_port`

- you can export https_proxy and socks_proxy if you need.
- To see if your proxy is set or not use `env | grep proxy`

To change system proxy using shell script try these:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'proxy.server.addr'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port proxy_port
```

If you have user authentication pass and id

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user 'user_id'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password 'password'
```

To use http_proxy for all other proxy

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
```

To set bypass proxy for any host

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost',  '127.0.0.1', 'all', 'other', 'hosts']"
```

Comment: Wow, this is still relevant and worked great for me on Ubuntu 18.04!