# How To Set System Wide Proxy Using Shell Script

Tags: 14.04, unity, networking, proxy, gsettings

I want to make a script that sets and unsets SYSTEM WIDE proxy just as what happens through the network settings.

I tried [this answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368945/how-to-set-system-wide-proxy-address-using-shell-script) gsettings part but it does not work in 14.04

Could Anyone please help? Its FRUSTRATING to open the network settings every time!

Comment: Tried http://askubuntu.com/a/526900/158442 ?

Comment: @muru Its not working! :(

Comment: "Its not working!" is meaningless. How is it not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: @muru No errors... but thge proxies are not picked up by any  browsers nor reflected in the network manager

Comment: How are you running it? What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode`?

Comment: it says 'manual'... but the changes dont take effect... logout isnt needed right?

Comment: Changes to `gsettings` and `apt.conf` should take effect immediately, but `/etc/environment` needs a logout. What about `gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy.http host`, or one of the other values, and the files `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `/etc/environment`? Are they changed?

Comment: @muru ... okay... i solved the issue... thanx a lot for the help... ill post what i did as the answer.. turns out i didnt need setting of proxy address as i have already done it through gui once... i just needed mode changing!

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

Here is what i did...

I just needed a 'Proxy Mode Changer'... 
Setting the proxies , i did through gui... Now i just needed changing mode...

Here is the script i made... SIMPLE as anything ->

```
#!/bin/bash

state=$(gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode)

if [ $state == "'none'" ]; then
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
elif [ $state == "'manual'" ]; then
        gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
fi
```