# How do gsettings interact and/or conflict with exported enviroment variables? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: command-line, scripts, 20.04, environment-variables, gsettings

I am behind a corporate fire wall and have been trying to set up my proxy settings by using `export` in a shell script located in `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` (see, e.g.,  [How to set system-wide proxy address using shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368945/how-to-set-system-wide-proxy-address-using-shell-script)).

While troubleshooting the settings, I also made changes in the "Network" GUI. I could not connect due to an error I introduced in the "Network" GUI, which I believe may have overridden the correct setting in the proxy.sh script file.

How does gsettings interact and/or conflict with environment variables set by scripts located in `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/environment`? Which settings take precedence if there is a conflict? If I am using Ubuntu Desktop (i.e., a GUI environment) is it preferably to edit environment variables using gsettings (either from the GUI or a script that sets gsettings) so that they are accessible in the GUI (i.e., I disabled the proxy settings in the GUI because they conflicted with my script, but now I cannot see the settings set by the script in the GUI)? Any thoughts on best practice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do not think the answer in the attached link will work. To expand a variable in a string, you must switch to double-quotes. You can use single-quotes inside a string like this: `export http_proxy="http://$1/"; gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "'$http_proxy'"`

Comment: The primary thrust of my question is how "gsettings interact and/or conflict with environment variables set by scripts". I.e., if they conflict, who wins and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't find creditable sources, I would say: "AFAIK, there is no global setting for PROXY in the current distributions of GNU/Linux & BSD. It is all up to the end user application to use or ignore proxy setting at any level: environment vars, desktop environment, config ... Similar case to DNS"

So, for many net tools (like: apt, firefox, wget, ...) they have their own proxy settings and priority list.

If you are looking for tool from Gnome Desktop Environment. Then probably, this is the interesting part:

gnome-core → glib-networking → libproxy1v5

> #### Config Modules
>
> Config modules read proxy configuration from a source. Every config module has a type.  There are three confnig
> types:  SYSTEM   Defines configuration on a system-wide
> basis   USER     Defines configuration on a user-wide basis
>
> SESSION  Defines configuration for this current login
> session only  A module can also choose to have no config type.
>
> The config module sources (as of 0.4.15) are:  direct 
> always return direct://, this is the global fallback
>
> envvar  reads http_proxy, https_proxy, ftp_proxy and no_proxy environment variables  gnome  reads gconf (SESSION)  gnome3  reads gsettings (SESSION)  kde  reads kconfig (SESSION)  wpad  always returns wpad://, this is used to fall back on autodetect if desired
>
> By default, modules are called in the following order:
>
> 1. USER
> 2. SESSION
> 3. SYSTEM
> 4. envvar
> 5. wpad
> 6. direct
>
> The order *within* the categories is undefined and could be random. If
> a module says it can't find the configuration, the next module is
> tried.
>
> The module order can be manually specified through an environmental
> variable (PX_CONFIG_ORDER).  The order indicated in this variable
> **does not replace** the internal order, but prepends to it.  Thus, if you wanted to prefer (for forcing a module, see whitelist/blacklist
> above) the usage of envvar, you would specify the following which
> would put envvar first in the list: `export PX_CONFIG_ORDER=config_envvar`
>
> You can also lock-down the module order for all users on a system
> using /etc/proxy.conf.  This feature is not yet documented (any
> volunteers!?).

Source: https://github.com/libproxy/libproxy/wiki/HowTo#config-modules